# Show / Hide Listview SectionIndex on demand

Tags: android, listview, indexing, hide

i implemented a listview which implements SectionIndexer ...
everything fine so far.

Normally the items are sorted by Name, but i also offer the option to sort the list in a different way - by distance (from the user to the objects).

So, when the list is sorted the 2nd way, i want to hide the previously generated SectionIndex.

I'm just not able to do so.

I tried, re-writting most of the methods,
I tried it with a separation in the Constructor (clear why it doesnt work, it doesnt get called a second time)
I even tried it with implementing a second listadapter, and just using a different one? Even in this case the SEctionIndex is shown! I really don't understand this one.

So would be really great, if anyone knows whats going on :)

thanks a lot, mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations are correct. Let me tell you first why the constructor never gets called the second time. SectionIndexer are a special kind. They create the index only once for a particular set of data and re-use them on that adapter. The bigger issue which I had come across was when the underlying data changed for the adapter, the sectionIndexer still remained the same.

Check my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141314/force-onsizechanged-for-listview) and the answer there.

Coming back to your query here.

If you change the orientation after selecting the second option, you would observe that the constructor will get called and you will be able to re-populate the sectionIndex again. So basically you need to call onSizeChanged again and get the sectionIndex repopulated.

Comment: i give you the bounty, you are correct, but please also review my answer below, i've checked my code and will post it here.. there's something additional you have to do, i'd suggest, just copy my posting below, edit yours, and add :=) the complete solution here. so everyone else has it easier to solve the problem :)

Comment: ACtually i added it to your post... "there was an edit button" ,below your post, i used it to post the code directly into your post, it seems like someone deleted it :(

Answer (score 0):

When you Short your List with different way ,you have a two option to load again .

after filled  those new collection  for adapter

**1)**  you can make a notify this adapter .

**2)**  you can fill set adapter again .

Comment: im sorry, but this prevent the section indexes to hide or disappear :(

Comment: it should not ..u have to manage the collection what gonna fill in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

If by SectionIndexer which remains displayed you mean the section overlay you can achieve this by calling [setFastScrollEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29) before to switch to your other listadapter which does not implements SectionIndexer.